# Normalize time series with different lengths with linear interpolation in R

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I have a large set of time series (100k, each 3 observations), their lengths varies about 10% on average. Each of them cover the time interval of the same lengths but varies  due to rate of sampling, this is the cause of differents lengths of time series vectors. I would like to normalize lenght of each pair using linear interpolation, such that first and last observation in each time series remains the same. Is there R function for such manipulation ?

Example R :

```
input <- 0:4 #should be rescaled/resized into :
output <- c(0, .444, .888, 1.333, 1.777, 2.222, 2.666, 3.111, 3.555, 4)
```

Comment: Seems like you want to use interpolation to get the same number of data points in each time series.  If so, the approxfun might do it.  It would be helpful if you posted a short example of your time series and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question and example I'll make a couple of assumptions-- First, that each set of input values are at equi-spaced intervals over a unit time interval.  Second, that the output is to be at equi-spaced intervals over a unit time interval.  Clearly if the length of time of the input and output  is something different from unity, these can be easily scaled to the actual time. So  the R code would look like:

```
# define the standardized x values of the output 
#
output_x_vals <- seq(0,1,length.out=10)
#
# compute the interpolated values; this would be done for each input time series
#
  interp_output<- approx(x=seq(0,1,length.out=length(input)), y=input, xout=output_x_vals)
```

For you example, interp_output is

```
interp_output
$x
[1] 0.0000000 0.1111111 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.6666667 0.7777778 0.8888889 1.0000000

$y
[1] 0.0000000 0.4444444 0.8888889 1.3333333 1.7777778 2.2222222 2.6666667 3.1111111 3.5555556 4.0000000
```

where \$x are the output x interpolation points and $y are the interpolated values.